# Object library not visible when click on .XIB in xcode ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After creating a new project I'm able to see object library, where I'm able to see many controls...But, Once I click on .XIB file, "object library" not visible and it got replaced by "objects".Please see attachment.[image: Object library]

[image: Objects]

Note: I see "pdfView" in object library, how can I use this in iOS?

Comment: I understood this from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859798/how-to-use-pdfview-in-object-library-in-ios/19859963?noredirect=1#comment29538006_19859963

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you've chosen a xib-file from OS X "User Interface" NOT from iOS "User Interface". From what I understand from your tags, you want iOS.

If you can't see the "Object Library" you probably just have to drag up the list from the bottom right of the window.

***Object Library not showing:***

[image]

***Object Library showing:***

[image]

Comment: If you can't see the "Object Library" you probably just have to drag up the list from the bottom right of the window. -> could you plaese be more specific? Note: I'm developing an iOS application.

Comment: Updated my answer. I can't really tell from your pictures, they are too small.

Comment: drag up the list from the bottom right of the window.-> neither able to drag nor able to see any thing.How can I do this??